# glReadPixels GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT does not work in mousePressEvent

Tags: qt, opengl

I am using QT **QOpenGLWidget**, I want to unproject my mouse click position back into 3D, so I used **glReadPixels**. (I also read about the source code of [Pangolin](https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin), a very good rotation, translation, zoom example, it uses glReadPixels as well)

Here's part of my simple code:

```
void myGLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    glClearColor(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0);                    //background color
    glClearDepthf(1.0);                                  //set depth test
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                             //enable depth test
}

void myGLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); //clear color and depth buffer

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadMatrixf(cameraView_.data());         // cameraView_  is a QMatrix4x4
    drawingTeapot();

    // reading pixels in paintGL works well!!! returns lots of 1s
    GLfloat zs[10 * 10];
    glReadPixels(0, 0, 10, 10, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &zs);
}

void myGLWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    // glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);      // also tried this, nothing works
    GLfloat zs[10 * 10];
    glReadPixels(0, 0, 10, 10, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &zs);
    GLenum e = glGetError();        // this gives 1282 err code!!!
}
```

I'm using macOS Sierra, [Pangolin](https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin) works perfectly on my laptop, however, my qt project does work??!!

By saying not working, I mean the output variable **zs** remains random values like 0 and 123123e-315 and it never change before and after glReadPixels.

**Why glReadPixels works only in PaintGL function??**

*I also tried python version*, *it gives my an error says*:

```
File "errorchecker.pyx", line 53, in OpenGL_accelerate.errorchecker._ErrorChecker.glCheckError (src/errorchecker.c:1218)
OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
    err = 1282,
    description = b'invalid operation',
    baseOperation = glReadPixels,
```

which might be the case that:
`GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if format is GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT and there is no depth buffer.` reference from [document](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glReadPixels.xhtml)

**But I still don't know what to do**

Comment: Inside your paint function the context is active. This is handled for you by Qt. In other places, you need to make the OpenGL context active manually.

Comment: @craig-zhang, @DietrichEpp is correct, can you try making the context current and see if it works? try `makeCurrent();` at the start of your `mousePressEvent()` method.

Comment: Thank you!!! @DietrichEpp, and Harish!, its working now

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL operations should be performed only when an OpenGL context is active. This is true in the paintGL() method because this is probably set by the framework for you. You can't assume the OpenGL is active in other methods, like in other event responding methods and callbacks as mousePressEvent(), because those methods can also be run by a different thread where the OpenGL context is not active.